# "towards" (vs."toward") her family

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

In this sentence, why need to use "towards" and not "toward"? As "responsibilities" is a plural noun already.

> A girl with big dreams but with even bigger responsibilities **towards** her family.

Comment: Where did you find this sentence? (You should always tell us where you found it, even if you wrote it. See [Why You Should Cite Your Source](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source) on our meta site.)

Answer (score 1):

The choice between *toward* and *towards* is generally a matter of style and region. *Toward* is more common in US English, while *towards* is more common in UK English.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toward):

> **toward** preposition
>   to·​ward | \ ˈtō-ərd, ˈtȯ(-ə)rd\
>   variants: or **towards** \ ˈtō-​ərd(z), ˈtȯ(-​ə)rd(z), tə-​ˈwȯrd(z), ˈtwȯrd(z) \

Note that use of *variants*. That means that the variant is accepted, but it's not as common. This is also stated explicitly under its adjective definition:

> **1** *or less commonly* **towards**

---

Meanwhile, the definition of [**towards**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/towards) used by Lexico (Oxford) shows:

> **towards**
>   (*North American* **toward**)

And under its definition of [*toward*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/toward):

> variant of **towards**

---

So while there is no absolute rule about this (it still comes down to style), it's generally more common to use *toward* in the US and *towards* in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

Most dictionary examples will tell you that you should follow the word with either "*to*" or "*for*", depending on the direction of the responsibility.

For example:

- An employer has a responsibility *for* his employees.
- An employee has a responsibility *to* his employer.

"Responsibility *towards*...." is used a whole lot less. [This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=responsibility%20to%2C%20responsibility%20for%2C%20responsibility%20towards%2C%20responsibility%20toward&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cresponsibility%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresponsibility%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresponsibility%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresponsibility%20toward%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cresponsibility%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresponsibility%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresponsibility%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresponsibility%20toward%3B%2Cc0) shows that it is barely used in comparison to the examples above.

Examples using "towards" tend to be *moral* responsibilities towards concepts, such as *a responsibility towards society*, or *a responsibility towards the environment*. I would say that you should only really use this expression when referring to similar concepts - where we are not under strict compulsion to carry out a responsibility, but where our thoughts and actions should perhaps be oriented to that cause.

Comment: I like this answer, but I think you should add something about "responsibility toward" vs. "responsibility towards"